# How to theme Nautilus' resize area/handle border?

Tags: customization, themes, 12.04, gtk3

I'd like to change the visual appearance of the marked resize border/areas in Nautilus:

[image]

If I knew how those elements are named in GTK+, I'm sure I could find out what I'd need to add to `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/apps/nautilus.css`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the last entry in */usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/apps/nautilus.css* to:

```
NautilusWindow > GtkTable .pane-separator {
    background-color: shade (@dark_bg_color, 1.1);
    border-width: 0;
}
```

to get this:

[image]

Instead of using just a single background color, you can also use a gradient:

```
NautilusWindow > GtkTable .pane-separator {
    background-image: -gtk-gradient (linear, left top, left bottom,
                                 from (shade (@dark_bg_color, 1.04)),
                                 to (shade (@dark_bg_color, 2.2)));
    border-width: 0;
}
```

If you want to remove the handle icon, you have to set the `-unico-inner-stroke-color` to transparent:

```
NautilusWindow > GtkTable .pane-separator {
    background-image: -gtk-gradient (linear, left top, left bottom,
                                 from (shade (@dark_bg_color, 1.04)),
                                 to (shade (@dark_bg_color, 2.2)));
    border-width: 0;

    -unico-inner-stroke-color: @transparent;
}
```

You can also change the thickness of the resize pane by adding this to the CSS file (will make the resize pane 3 pixels thick):

```
NautilusWindow * {
    -GtkPaned-handle-size: 3;
}
```

The final thing looks like this:

[image]

Thanks to Andrea Cimitan for helping a bit. ;-)

Comment: How to edit style (I mean which selectors/classes to use) of single row of list in nautilus file manager in Ubuntu 20.04 GTK3? I have searched everywhere, but cannot find this information anywhere.